# Repeated Measures Experiment with multiple measures per condition, varying in length

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have data from a driving experiment. We measured distance to the leading vehicle at specific triggers as dependent variable. Participants drove the track twice: with and without assistance. 
However, we did not control how the participants drove. Thus, we have multiple measures per condition from the same participant, but not paired.

So far I analyzed my data using a Wilcoxon test on the mean distances per participant. The difference is significant, but since the distances seem not to be normally distributed, it appears odd to me to work with means.

Is there a "best practice" to check for significant effects for this kind of experiment?

It seems like trying a regression analysis could work, especially using GLM. However, I could not find information about how to account for the within-subjects factor (i.e. "participant").

**Here is an example to help you understand my data:**

```
    # create the data
    library(plyr)
    participant = as.factor(sample(1:20, 400 , replace = T))
    mode = as.factor(sample(c("with","without"), 400, replace = T))
    distance = 5-log(rnorm(400, mean=4, sd=1), base=2)
    df = data.frame(participant, mode ,distance)
    df = df[with(df, order(participant, mode)),]
    df$uid = seq.int(nrow(df))
    df_min = aggregate(uid ~ mode + participant, df, FUN = min)
    df_min = rename(df_min, c('uid'='maneuver_id'))
    df = merge(df, df_min)
    df$maneuver_id = df$uid - df$maneuver_id

    # add offset for difference per mode
    df[df$mode == 'with', 'distance'] = df[df$mode == 'with', 'distance']  + runif(nrow(df[df$mode == 'with',]), min=-.1, max = .8)
    # add offset for difference per time (measured with maneuver_id)
    df$distance = df$distance + df$maneuver_id * runif(400, min= -.03, max = .06)

    # Analysis
    ## Wilcoxon
    df_aggr = aggregate(distance ~ mode + participant, df, FUN=mean)
    df_wide = spread(df_aggr, mode, distance, fill=NA)
    wilcox.test(df_wide$with, df_wide$without, paired = T)

    ## GLM
    # How to add participant?!
    glm(distance ~ maneuver_id + mode, df, family = gaussian) 

    ## GLMER
    # Is this correct?
    library(lme4)
    model = glmer(distance ~ maneuver_id + mode  + ( maneuver_id | (participant)), data=df, gaussian(link='log'))
    summary(model)
```